# row summing selectively in tidyverse (dplyr) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a quick `tidyverse` questions. In `gg`:

How can I subtract the values of `salary` for rows (`1` - `3`), and then (`2` - `4`) and then subtract them from each other. Overall, that is: rows (`1` - `3`) - (`2` - `4`)

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/salary.csv')

gg <- data %>% dplyr::select(female,over10,salary) %>% group_by(over10,female) %>% 
summarise(across(.fns = mean), n = n())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned this in your post but I think why you want to subtract rows c(1, 3) and (2, 4) is because of (0, 1) values in `female` column. If that is so you can `group_by` `female` column and calculate the difference using `diff`.

```
library(dplyr)
gg %>%
  group_by(female) %>%
  summarise(salary = diff(salary)) %>%
  summarise(salary = -diff(salary))

# salary
#   <dbl>
#1  13891.
```

If you really want to do this based on the row numbers you can do :

```
diff(gg$salary[c(1, 3)] - gg$salary[c(2, 4)])
#[1] 13891.
```

Comment: Do you mean `gg %>% group_by(female) %>% summarise(sd = sd(salary))` ?

Comment: Ohh..you mean in your original `data` ? You can apply multiple functions together. `data %>% 
  select(female,over10,salary) %>%
  group_by(over10,female) %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = list(mn = mean, sd = sd)), n = n())`